# rails: how to have a FactoryGirl for all my states

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Say I have a event_type model which has a few event types such as "live","used","offline".

Those types are used in my other model called Event. Now, when testing, I need to have all types populated on every run. To be more specific, this is my event Factory:

```
factory :event do |e|
    e.event_type {|v| v.association(:event_type)}
    e.latitude 40.767929000000
    e.longitude -73.985742000000
end
```

I tried this on the event factory:

```
after(:create) {|event|
  FactoryGirl.create(:event_type, {:name => "live"})
  FactoryGirl.create(:event_type, {:name => "used"})
  FactoryGirl.create(:event_type, {:name => "offline"})
}
```

The problem with this approach is that if I create more than one event object all event types are created again for each event I use.

What would be a better approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this in the _spec that is running the test. (or the test)

In RSpec you'd do this in a before block at the top of your spec.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Event do 

  before do 
    FactoryGirl.create(:event_type, {:name => "live"})
    FactoryGirl.create(:event_type, {:name => "used"})
    FactoryGirl.create(:event_type, {:name => "offline"}) 
  end

  it "tests something" do 
    ...
  end 
end
```

also you're probably trying to do what Trait was made for ... so in your Factory

```
factory :event do |e|

  e.latitude 40.767929000000
  e.longitude -73.985742000000

  trait :live
    e.event_type = "live"
  end

  trait :used
    e.event_type = "used"
  end

  trait :offline
    e.event_type = "offline"
  end

  # defining these is not necessary but may save you some time
  factory :event_live, traits: [:live]
  factory :event_used, traits: [:used]
  factory :event_offline, traits: [:offline]
end
```

Which would allow you to create Factories based on them as such:

```
FactoryGirl.create :event, :live
```

Or you could call the "unnecessary factories" shown above

```
FactoryGirl.create :event_live
```

However if event_type is an association then you might need the traits to be defined in a separate factory which you can leverage like this:

```
trait :live do 
  e.association :event_type, factory: :event_type
end
```

Hope this helps!

You may also want to leverage the [Database Cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner.git) gem to clear out items between each run so you don't run into unique validation errors.

Comment: It does help, thank you! But is there a way to create those events globally and not before each spec?

Comment: Generally (at least IMO) you want to start with an empty database before each run, so I would advise creating them each run. However you can put them in "describe Event do" and then nest additional describe blocks within that one. These events will be present for each nested describe block. :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be populating values directly in to the test database. If you're using transactional fixtures (config.use_transactional_fixtures = true in spec_helper), you shouldn't have to worry about it getting accidentally removed. If you put it into a fixture, you can easily reimport it if it does get lost.

Comment: This sounds more like an advice than the answer, please add these in the comments for the question and once you have enough info, provide an answer for the user that they can implement